# How to remove game sounds in Agore Voice

Tags: agora.io, agora, agora-implementation

Hi I am using Agora Voice Chat unity sdk in my game. It is communicating between players but also sending button click or games sounds to other users. I want only to send human voice to the other users not system voices.
@agora.io

Regards

Agora Unity SDK
I want to sent only human voices only not along with game button clicks along with human voice.